# using different storage engines per partition

Tags: mysql, performance, postgresql, partitioning, mariadb

I have a large amount of historic 'closed' rows - three months of data, likely to be one or two terabytes - and a smaller amount of high-churn 'open' rows - upto 3 days of data, but most rows are likely to transition to the 'closed' state after  just a few minutes.

Ideally I want these presented to SELECT queries as a single conceptual table.

But under the hood, I'm keen for the 'closed' rows to be partitioned by customer_id and to be aggressively compressed and so on.  For the 'open' rows, I may have to update them several times in quick succession before I finally move them to the 'closed' state.

How can I divide my data up?

- MERGE tables seem to be myISAM only
- SPIDER and CONNECT mean multiple servers?
- PARTITION doesn't let you specify engines and compression per partition,
- and SUBPARTITION cannot be specified on a PARTITION basis?
- and 'closed' boolean would have to be in the primary key?
- if I had two tables UNIONed by a VIEW, would the query planner understand how to avoid running against all tables?
- do partitions speed up SELECTs that touch multiple partitions e.g. workers in parallel?

Or could this be done efficiently in a different DBMS instead e.g. PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having two separate tables, one for your archives and one for your working set. I don't think MySQL views are smart enough to optimize this.  It would also give you complete control over the schema but puts the burden on your application.